# Reshape table for tile plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like this (I have simplified it, its very long in reality).

[image]

```
data <- structure(list(miRs = structure(c(10L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 8L), .Label = c("bantam", "miR-1", "miR-184|example1", 
"miR-184|example2", "miR-184|example3", "miR-184|example4", "miR-3", 
"miR-7", "miR-9", "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2", "miR-92|example3"
), class = "factor"), Apis.mellifera = structure(c(8L, 9L, 10L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bantam", 
"miR-1", "miR-184|example1", "miR-184|example2", "miR-184|example3", 
"miR-184|example4", "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2", "miR-92|example3"
), class = "factor"), B..morix = structure(c(9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bantam", "miR-1", 
"miR-10", "miR-184|example1", "miR-184|example2", "miR-184|example3", 
"miR-184|example4", "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2"), class = "factor"), 
    D..mel = structure(c(8L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bantam", "miR-1", "miR-184|example1", 
    "miR-184|example2", "miR-184|example3", "miR-184|example4", 
    "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2", "miR-92|example3"), class = "factor"), 
    N..vitripennis = structure(c(8L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bantam", "miR-1", "miR-184|example1", 
    "miR-184|example2", "miR-184|example3", "miR-184|example4", 
    "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2", "miR-92|example3"), class = "factor"), 
    P..tepidariorum = structure(c(9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bantam", "miR-1", "miR-10", 
    "miR-184|example1", "miR-184|example2", "miR-184|example3", 
    "miR-184|example4", "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2"), class = "factor"), 
    T..castaneum = structure(c(8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125", 
    "miR-1", "miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1795", "miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1950", 
    "miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1952", "miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1954", 
    "miR-92|example1", "miR-92|example2", "miR-92|example3"), class = "factor"), 
    S..maritima = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "miR-3", "miR-7", "miR-9"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Ideally I want to make a tile plot, where only absence/presence of a each miR is shown. However, I am having a lot of travel to reshape this table on R or to even plot it. The desired output would be: 
[image]

And I would like to plot that. 
Any help with this problem will be very much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tidyr::pivot_longer` and `ggplot` from the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -miRs, names_to = "species", values_to = "listed_miRs") %>%
  ggplot(aes(species, listed_miRs)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I also got to that result too doing this:

a = melt(data = c, id.vars = "miRs")
p <- ggplot(a, aes(variable, value)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))

Thanks for your super quick help !

Comment: Do you know any way to cluster the results in the ggplot in order to avoid the holes?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what resorting makes sense for your data, but you might start by looking at the `forcats` package, especially `forcats::fct_reorder` or `forcats::fct_infreq`.

Answer (score 1):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then do a `count` and reshape it back to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -miRs) %>% 
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  count(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R`

```
+(table(unlist(data), rep(names(data), each = nrow(data))) != 0)
```